# Gupshup Flow bot not working now

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, gupshup

Gupshup integrated bot on facebook messenger not working on any pages but were working fine previously(until like one week back). Tested on Gupshup Proxy bot today and they were working fine.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Like the bot name on Gupshup and which page it is associated to etc

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Somehow the publishing is broken. We at Gupshup are working to get this fixed quickly.

Comment: Thanks shreyans. Saw you testing it and things are working fine now. Thanks lots!

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues with publishing which has been fixed now. Both of the bots [JurongNeighbourhoodAgent](https://www.messenger.com/t/JurongNeighbourhoodAgent) and [latesteclaunch](https://www.messenger.com/t/latesteclaunch) are working fine.